# What is the meaning of "integration" in Calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I can see that "differentiation" is about the "dy" - because it is the difference between 2 adjacent y values. But if I view integration as sum of Reimann rectangles, and if one Reimann rectangle's area is (y . dx) why is that called "integration?"  Maybe "integration" means "sum" of all the Reimann rectangles?

I guess "Sum" is easier to understand. I just don't get what "integration" label indicates. What are we "putting together" (as opposed to "differentiating"). Thanks!

Comment: "Integration" means putting things together. Yes, putting together the rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Both concepts: differentiation and integration are distinct. The derivative of a function was “created” to calculate the slope of a tangente line of a curve $y=f(x)$, while the (definite o Riemann) integral was “created” to calculate the area between the curve $y=f(x)$ and the $X$-axis.

But both concepts are strongly related by Leibniz’s rule (one of the forms of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Comment: Thanks! I thought more about this. And I guess what I am asking is this: graphically speaking, how come area under the curve (sum or integration) turns out to be "anti-" of slope (derivative)?  Seems I have not fully internalized FTC.

Comment: @SaurinP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Geometric_meaning